# Images are not getting fetched from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso

I have tried the normal way creating custom adapter class and also default FirebaseRecyclerAdapter but the images are not loading up efficiently.

Aim is to load images from firebase But the message queue is long , Please suggest some Solutions.

In this MainActivity.java file, I have used  FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
private DatabaseReference imagesReference = databaseReference.child("Images");




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);

        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);



        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageUrl,MyViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ImageUrl, MyViewHolder>(
         new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ImageUrl>().setQuery(imagesReference.limitToLast(50),ImageUrl.class).build()
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ImageUrl model) {
                holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),model.getUrl());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_grid_layout,parent,false);
                MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
                return myViewHolder;
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here I have used Picasso to load images,

MyViewHolder.java file :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    ImageView imageView;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void setDetails(Context mContext, String url){
        Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse(url)).into(imageView);
    }
}
```

I am getting in logcat like this :

```
2021-04-14 00:47:19.148 4019-4048/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2021-04-14 00:47:19.475 4019-4045/com.example.thoughtsdemo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
2021-04-14 00:47:19.477 4019-4045/com.example.thoughtsdemo I/System.out: e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
2021-04-14 00:47:19.950 4019-4045/com.example.thoughtsdemo D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
2021-04-14 00:47:19.951 4019-4045/com.example.thoughtsdemo D/OpenSSLLib: OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
```

In logcat in red it is showing like this :

```
2021-04-14 13:31:51.560 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
2021-04-14 13:31:51.560 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-1m33s688ms what=159 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction@fb63a696 } , cost  = 90743 ms
2021-04-14 13:31:51.560 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
2021-04-14 13:31:51.561 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-1m33s432ms what=149 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@622d88c }
2021-04-14 13:31:51.562 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2>  = { when=-1m30s168ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2021-04-14 13:31:51.562 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3>  = { when=-1m30s162ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2021-04-14 13:31:51.563 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <4>  = { when=-1m20s754ms what=132 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H }
2021-04-14 13:31:51.563 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <5>  = { when=-26ms what=0 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler callback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$4 }
2021-04-14 13:31:51.563 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <6>  = { when=-9ms barrier=0 }
2021-04-14 13:31:51.563 30382-30382/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
```

ImageUrl.java :

```
public class ImageUrl {

String url;

public ImageUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public ImageUrl(){

}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

}

Whem I used Log.d() to display fetched url in onBindViewHolder , I am not getting URL printed so problem is here:

```
 protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ImageUrl model) {
               Log.d("url",model.getUrl());
                holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),model.getUrl());

            }
```

In Red written stuff in logcat when I used Glide,

```
    2021-04-14 17:28:03.148 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
2021-04-14 17:28:03.148 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-34s879ms what=159 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction@7f3731c5 } , cost  = 31829 ms
2021-04-14 17:28:03.148 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
2021-04-14 17:28:03.149 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-34s610ms what=149 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=android.os.BinderProxy@622d88c }
2021-04-14 17:28:03.149 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2>  = { when=-31s140ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2021-04-14 17:28:03.150 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3>  = { when=-31s134ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2021-04-14 17:28:03.150 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <4>  = { when=-21s840ms what=132 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H }
2021-04-14 17:28:03.151 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <5>  = { when=-37ms what=0 target=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler callback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$4 }
2021-04-14 17:28:03.151 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <6>  = { when=-10ms barrier=0 }
2021-04-14 17:28:03.151 16789-16789/com.example.thoughtsdemo E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
```

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: have you used the debugger to identify that at which particular line, you are getting this error ?

Comment: probably something wrong with your `Uri.parse(url)`

Comment: @YoushaBinArif I have tried debugging but it is showing no problem, In logcat it is showing in red like this :

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher I tried different things but it is not having problem with "URL".

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide

**Add Dependency:**

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

**How to load image:**

```
Glide.with(CONTEXT).load(URL).into(IMAGE_VIEW);
```

NOTE: Replace with your own values.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: I tried implementing Glide but still there is no fetching of images, I have edited my question about problem I am facing .

Comment: Kindly update the log , after using Glide.

Comment: And I found out that it is not the problem of Picasso or glide. See My first logcat in the question asked.

Comment: Please suggest Solutions